# Send associative array to magento by POST using CURL

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, magento2

I need to send this array

```
$places = [
    [
        'name' => 'K',
        'region_id' => 'UH',
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'enabled' => 1
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'G',
        'region_id' => 'MS',
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'enabled' => 0
    ]
];
```

to Magento2 module by POST in JSON. Module must put it to DB table;

I try to send JSON array

```
{
        "places":
    [
        {
            "name":"K",
            "region_id":"UH",
            "date":"2016-10-18 4:12:22",
            "enabled":"1"
        },
        {
            "name":"G",
            "region_id":"MS",
            "date":"2016-10-18 4:12:32",
            "enabled":"1"
        }
    ]
}
```

but getting error

> Notice: Array to string conversion in  vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php on line 505 in
>   vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195

Help, please.

Comment: Its not an error, its a notice? Which means: "You probably shouldn't be doing what you're doing, but I'll let you do it anyway"

Comment: Can you share the code, where you convert your array to json?

Comment: I'll get this massage and don't get a result; I don't convert array to json, i just send JSON array via CURL: 
curl -d '{
        "places": [
      {
            "name":"K",
            "region_id":"UH",
            "date":"2016-10-18 4:12:22",
            "enabled":"1"
        },
        {
            "name":"G",
            "region_id":"MS",
            "date":"2016-10-18 4:12:32",
            "enabled":"1"
        }
    ]
}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://127.0.0.1/index.php/rest/V1/informs/take

Comment: @nerdlyist, i think this framework makes

Comment: @nerdlyist, when i send     {
            "places":
            {
                "name":"K",
                "region_id":"UH",
                "date":"2016-10-18 4:12:22",
                "enabled":"1"
            }
    } everything is OK. My module just get encoded array $places.

Comment: @nerdlyist i do not use json_decode() or jsone_encode() functions. That's makes Magento.

Comment: please share the relevant code.